# Test passes in IDE, fails on command line

Tags: java, maven, testing, ide

The tests writes stuff to a file and then reads from a file to make sure some things happen. The tests (always) pass in my IntelliJ.

When running `mvn clean install`, the test fails with

`java.io.FileNotFoundException: log/sample1_2013-09-17.log (No such file or directory)`

What could explain this consistency?

Comment: are you executing the maven command in the same directory as the code you're running on IntelliJ

Comment: Doublechecked that and yes. Additionally, order in which tests run does not seem to make a difference

Comment: is the clean action deleting the log directory and the install is not re-creating it? (just shooting in the dark with the information you've provided)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IntelliJ must be running the tests in a different working directory than in the command line.

What I would do is make sure that the command-line `mvn` succeeds by moving the `log` directory (and any other resources) to the appropriate directory.  Back in IntelliJ, you can specify the working directory to be used.  Use the same working directory as the working directory where `mvn` succeeds.